# SQL Server: Find records where XML is missing tag

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have table named: XMLIndex that contains a column named: XMLRec that holds the structure of an XML file and values.

Some of these records are missing a tag named: `<ISO></ISO>`

My question is: what type of query do I need to run in order to find all the records in the table XMLIndex, that are missing the `<ISO>` tag?

This is an example XMLRecord XML that contains the ISO tag:

```
<XMLRecord>
  <pn>0042761</pn>
  <SRI>4.40</SRI>
  <igm>/images/images/0042761.gif</img>
  <ISO>ZW</ISO>
  <ListPrice>$5.50</ListPrice>  
</XMLRecord>
```

and one with multiple ISOs (look at the tag small difference):

```
<XMLRecord>
  <pn>0042762</pn>
  <SRI>4.40</SRI>
  <igm>/images/images/0042762.gif</img>
  <ISOs>ZW+NZ+AU+BR</ISOs>
  <ListPrice>$5.50</ListPrice>  
</XMLRecord>
```

One record missing the ISO tag is one that the XML structure would not contain such tag.

Any examples are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Trivial solution would be to cast it to nvarchar and do a NOT LIKE %<ISO>%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [XQuery exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method.

Check anywhere in the xml document:

```
select *
from XMLIndex
where XMLRec.exist('//ISO') = 0
```

Check a specific location:

```
where XMLRec.exist('/XMLRecord/ISO') = 0
```